# Google pay button not showing in flutter_stripe package payment sheet

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, google-pay

I used flutter_stripe: ^3.3.0 to implement stripe payment, everything goes well but I can't see google pay button on top of stripe payment sheet. I have enable google pay according to https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet. and below is what i am getting.

[image]

```
  Future<void> makePayment(
  {String amount,String currency}) async {
  try {
  paymentIntentData = await createPaymentIntent(amount, currency);
  if (paymentIntentData != null) {
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(         
      applePay: true,
      googlePay: true,
      testEnv: true,
      merchantCountryCode: 'US',
      merchantDisplayName: 'Prospects',
      customerId: paymentIntentData['customer'],
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData['client_secret'],
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentData['ephemeralKey'],
    ));
    displayPaymentSheet();
  }
} catch (e, s) {
  print('exception:$e$s');
}
}
```

Comment: Can you see the Google Pay button at this link in mobile Chrome on that device? https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button. If not, then it's a problem with your wallet/setup. Otherwise, it could be code-related.

Comment: This is regarding flutter app

Comment: Yes I understand. That link is for troubleshooting if it's an issue with your code or wallet.

Comment: Okay. Problem solved

Comment: i am also facing the same problem using `flutter_stripe 9.2.2` how do u fix it?